# how to clear phone number and user from about device status - galaxy S5

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-5, sim-card

Getting my Sprint Galaxy S5 ready to sell.  I've tried factory reset.  Even went into android recovery menu and wiped cache and factory wipe reset.  Yet when I go into settings -> about device -> status:  I see my user names (something like myname@samsung.com) and my phone number!   How do I wipe this?  I think I found the answer once before online when I was selling another phone a few months ago, but can't remember what it was.  I think I had to type some special #*#* into the dial pad to get it to wipe.  I think the info is store on the sim card.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  Dial ##72786#   This restores all phone setup information to the original factory settings.  It is *NOT* the same a factory reset.  It removes completely the old phone number and old user name from the phone.

I found the answer here, near the bottom of the page; post #13 on the page:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-ii-epic-4g-touch/254641-how-do-i-remove-my-user-name-phone-etc-settings.html

Answering my own question to hopefully help someone else ;-)